# My account has not been revealed

Tags: account, transfer, kt1

A few days ago I moved my tezos into my tezbox wallet, this was opened a few days ago too so should be the latest version. I followed the instructions to open a KT account but, it simply opened another TZ account.

Thinking it was all too complicated I tried to move to atomic wallet to stake from there but, even though my TZ balance is showing in the main account when I try to transfer it says that the account has not yet been revealed? But, there are no instructions on how to get it revealed or why it has not been.

I seem to be stuck!

I cannot seem to get the KT account opened to stake and I cannot get the tezos out either.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome @Sarah. Tezbox is considered defunct/unmaintained. It is good of you to move off of it. KT1's are not needed anymore; that's why it was creating a tz1 for you.

Your best bet is to just restore your wallet directly to Atomic using your mnemonic recovery words, or use Tezbox's 'export private key' function and import that key into Atomic directly.

Remember, your tokens are *not* stored within any wallet; they are stored on the chain and wallet software simply lets you interact with the chain.